# Markdown to HTML online converters not converting spoiler tags properly

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers

Context: When I write questions or answers on puzzling.stackexchange.com, I want to copy paste these questions and answers to my own site also. I believe that puzzling.stackexchange uses Markdown and I understand the formatting rules.

Now, I want to copy-paste this text written in Markdown to my website which only accepts HTML. I tried several online converters to convert the Markdown I have written to HTML. But none was able to convert the spoiler tags properly. I will give an example. When I write the following in puzzling.stackexchange:

[image: Markdown source of answer with spoilers]

I get the following result when I type the above on puzzling.stackexchange.com:

[image: Online rendering of answer with spoilers]

But when I type the exact above text on dillinger.io (or for that matter, any of the many online Markdown to HTML converters I have used) I get the following result:

[image: Rendering of Markdown to HTML converter, where the spoilers look like blockquotes with exclamation marks at the start of lines]

**Which online Markdown to HTML converter can I use to convert the spoiler tags properly?**

Comment: Spoiler is not supported in Markdown. it is an Stack Exchange only extension. No external markdown to html service will understand the markdown `>!` and if it does, it is by accident, not by design.

Comment: @rene , is there an converter to convert text written on stackexchange to html such that the spoiler tag also gets converted ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: There's a site called [puzzling.se] which will automatically do Markdown to HTML conversion of every question and answer which you post there. It even understands spoilers, `>!`. It will show you the HTML for your Markdown just by visiting the page on which you've posted your question or answer. It also has a live editor with preview, although the conversion by the online preview is not *quite* the same as what the backend will produce when you submit your question or answer for formatting. There's even [an API](//api.stackexchange.com/docs) from which you can get the HTML and Markdown.

Comment: As for the SE API, you could get the Markdown and HTML for every post you've made on [puzzling.se] by using [this API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-users#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=57212&filter=!4-2-FbzQG*kHPi6\(*&site=puzzling&run=true) ([raw SE API URL](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/57212/posts?order=desc&sort=activity&site=puzzling&filter=!4-2-FbzQG*kHPi6\(*)).

Comment: @Makyen maybe I read something different in the question but I assumed they had markdown on an SE post and now want to re-use that on their own site. While your comments are somewhat helpful I guess a piece of the puzzle is still missing. How would they get spoilers to work from the raw html?

Comment: @rene , you are right .. I want the posts I have made  on SE to look more or less the same when I convert them to html and use them on my own site . And the spoiler tag, etc should work as well.

Comment: This question would [probably be better asked](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=+html+markdown+converter) on Stack Overflow, or another site; this isn't on-topic for here.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal You asked specifically for "questions or answers **I write** on puzzling.stackexchange.com", so I gave you a URL which provides *your* questions and answers as HTML. If you want the HTML for some random question, then that's a [different URL for a different SE API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=1834&filter=!9_bDDucDa&site=puzzling&run=true).

Comment: @rene I read the question fairly explicitly as asking the XY question of "Where can I find an online Markdown converter that converts SE Markdown, including spoiler tags, into HTML?" Their real problem is "There are posts on [puzzling.se] which I want to copy onto my site, which takes HTML (and I'm not telling you anything else about it; e.g. if I can add CSS or JavaScript)". The information I provided was sufficient to cover what they asked for, but not solve their actual underlying problem, because the OP didn't ask about their actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which online Markdown to HTML converter can I use to convert the spoiler tag properly?

None of the online Markdown-to-HTML converters will do that because the spoiler markup `>!` is a Stack Exchange only extension. [CommonMark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#CommonMark) doesn't know about it and if other Markdown specifications do support it, that will be an accident.

It is worth noting that there isn't any `spoiler` tag in the HTML standard either, although I do see some fiddling with `<details><summary></summary></details>` as an option so that might evolve into a supported solution in 6 to 8 weeks.

You have to provide your own solution for the spoilers on your own website, preferable in your CSS. There isn't any common standard to solve this and the implementation from SE is proprietary.

The Stack Exchange HTML content for an spoiler looks like:

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler">
  <p> They are the same.</p>
</blockquote>
```

and without extra measures that will show as such. By adding a CSS style you can do a simple *hide* and reveal logic when the user hovers over the spoiler. This simplistic approach looks like this:

```css
/* prevent the spoiler from showing */
.spoiler {
  background-color: grey;
  color: grey;
}

/* show the spoiler on hover */
.spoiler:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

For more delicate and advanced spoiler reveals search on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+spoiler).

The below stack snippet will fetch the raw HTML content for a post on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), put that in the textarea for each copy-paste and show the fetched HTML with the above CSS to demonstrate the solution as a proof of concept. It is up to you to turn this into something that fits your website.

```js
function findfirst(tag) {
  return document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
}

findfirst('button').addEventListener('click',() => {
  var postid = findfirst('input').value;
  var url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/' + postid +'?order=desc&sort=activity&site=puzzling&filter=!-.HCYoi88k1L';

  fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
      findfirst('textarea').value = data.items[0].body;
      findfirst('div').innerHTML = data.items[0].body;
      });
});
```

```css
/* prevent the spoiler from showing */
.spoiler {
  /*border: 1px red solid; */
  background-color: grey;
  color: grey;
}

/* show the spoiler on hover */
.spoiler:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>

<hr>
<input value='1834'/><button>go</button><br>
<p>copy:</p>
<textarea style='font-family: monospace' disabled=disabled cols = 100 rows=100>
</textarea>
```

The minimal steps you have to do to have the HTML of a Stack Exchange post in a single HYML file:

- Click the big blue button above: *Run code snippet*
- Enter the postid you want the HTML for in the input box (your latest example is 107918)
- Click the button "go"

[image]

- Select all text in the TextArea (under the "GO" button) and copy to your clipboard

[image]

- Switch to you CodeBeatify.org site.
- Paste your clipboard.

[image]

- Switch back to this tutorial
- Copy the script and style tags found at the bottom of this answer to your clipboard

[image]

- Switch back to CodeBeautify.org
- Paste the script and style tags **above** the HTML you already have.

[image]

- Success!

Here is an example in JSBIN for your latest attempt:

https://jsbin.com/tijupiwigi/1/edit?html,output

## Script and Style tags

Notice that you need all the stuff that is in the `<script>` and `<style>` tags that you see in the head. That is for MathJax and Spoiler support. For completeness, this is the relevant HEAD content:

```html
<script>
    MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  },
  svg: {
    fontCache: 'global'
  }
};
  </script>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.1/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
  </script>
  <style>
  /* prevent the spoiler from showing */
  .spoiler {
    /*border: 1px red solid; */
    background-color: grey;
    color: grey;
  }

  /* show the spoiler on hover */
  .spoiler:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }    
  </style>
```

Comment: Ok, I am still learning html so not completely sure of what all needs to be done here . Let us say that I wish to copy the following answer to my site with the exact formatting as the one that I have used :  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1834/57212    . I tried doing so by just replacing "url" with https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/107918/57212  in fetch(url)  . This is the result that I had gotten   : https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/cbb6ba04 What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal the idea was that you use the code snippet to obtain the html you need based on the postid and then copy / paste that in your own HTML template. I've added extra instructions and an example on JSBIN.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I can't get that codebeatify to save my work so I made a screenshot instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3JIu.png

Comment: But the html on the left hand side of the image above, cannot be the original input html . It already contains text from my post . What was the html that you used to generate the left hand side html, is what I am asking ?

Comment: I copied and paste it, following the recipe in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you soo much . I understand now and it is working ..didn't realise that the tool to execute all this was also included by you.

Comment: There is one small thing though . In stackexchange, once you you have revealed a spoiler, it stays revealed, even if you take away the cursor away from it. Also, before a spoiler is revealed, there is text written on top of it, which says "Reveal spoiler" .  I also want it to say on the post copied to my site, "reveal spoiler" till a spoiler is not revealed and also, once a spoiler is revealed, i want it to stay that way. I don't want it to again get hidden as soon as the cursor is removed from over it.But when a cursor is removed from the text your code generates, the text again gets hidden.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Yeah, I was afraid you would ask that but that would require some javascript code (I think) and more CSS styling and what I have provided so far is the best I can do. I offered a search to spoiler logic on Stack Overflow but you've to do the effort to make that fit for your use-case. It is outside of what I'm able to do as well without serious digging and studying / experimenting. I can't spend the time on it.

Comment: possible to do either of the two things I asked or do both require digging ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Both is digging. I'm not a front-end dev so you're lucky I found/remembered the CSS trick. I don't fancy getting drunk over doing any more CSS and Javascript. I had hoped the spoiler stuff was part of [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/) but I couldn't find it there so that is why I did my simplistic/minimalistic CSS rules and left it at that.